# noarch conflicts with file from package pgdg-redhat-repo-42.0-15.noarch when update

Tags: fedora, yum

Today I am using this command to update my Fedora 32:

```
sudo yum update
```

shows this error:

```
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
The downloaded packages were saved in cache until the next successful transaction.
You can remove cached packages by executing 'dnf clean packages'.
Error: Transaction test error:
  file /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-PGDG from install of pgdg-fedora-repo-42.0-15.noarch conflicts with file from package pgdg-redhat-repo-42.0-15.noarch
```

I am searching from internet but found no one encount this problem. What should I do to fix it?

Comment: Did you try running `yum clean all` or `yum reinstall pgdg-redhat-repo-42.0-15.noarch`?

Comment: `yum remove pgdg-redhat-repo-42.0-15.noarch` fix it.